# Estimating sums with restrictions to different Frequencies

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have problems understanding two (for my research important) details in the Proof of Theorem 4 (page 14) in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1518. Notation is very straightforward and is found on page 4.
I expect that both issues are in reality the same problem:

1. In the first line of page 14 Schottdorf claims:
   $$S_1=\sum_NN^{2s}||P_N \sum_H \sum_{L<<H}I^+(u_L,v_H)||_{U^2_+}^2\color{red}{\lesssim}\sum_HH^{2s}||P_H \sum_{L<<H}I^+(u_L,v_H)||_{U^2_+}^2\lesssim||u||_{Y^s}^2||v||_{Y^s}^2$$
2. The line below he claims for $S_2$ (I just plugged in the Definition of $X^s$)
   $$S_2\leq \sum_H\sum_{H\sim H'}(\sum_LL^{2s}||P_LI^+(u_{H'},v_H)||_{U^2_+}^2)^{1/2}\color{red}{\lesssim}  \sum_H\sum_{H\sim H'}(\sum_{L\lesssim H}L^{2s}||P_LI^+(u_{H'},v_H)||_{U^2_+}^2)^{1/2}$$

In both problems some Frequencies are just discarded, that should mean that the corresponding terms are 0 and that is probably because the Littlewood Paley Projectors $P_L$ and $P_H$ are on different Frequencies. However if that would always work then the considererd integral term $I^+(u_{L},v_H)$ would always be 0 which wouldn't make sense. Can somebody help me understand the highlighted inequalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question 1 (and I expect the answer to question 2 is similar):

Note that $I^+(f,g)$ first take the product $fg$ and act on it as a Fourier multiplier. So the frequency support of $I^+(f,g)$ is the same as that of $fg$.

Now, when $L \ll H$ you have that the frequency support of $u_L v_H$ is $\approx H$, using that $2^H \pm 2^L \approx 2^H$ in this case. (You actually have the support being in $[H-3,H+3]$ or something similar depending on how you defined the cut-off functions.) So this tells you that

$$ P_N I^+(u_L, v_H) \neq 0 \iff N \approx H $$

which means in the sum over $N$ and $H$, you only need to sum "diagonally" over the $N\approx H$ terms since all the rest are zero.

Comment: That does work for question 1 but if I use that on question 2 I get ( since $H \approx H'$):

$$ P_L I^+(u_{H'}, v_H) \neq 0 \iff L \approx H  (:\iff L\lesssim H \ or \ H \lesssim L)$$

but for the estimation in question 2 to work I would need
$$ P_L I^+(u_{H'}, v_H) \neq 0 \iff L\lesssim H$$

Therefore I don't understand why he can ignore the sum over $H\lesssim L$ there.

Comment: Two points: (1) $L = H \iff (L\leq H \text{ and } H \leq L)$. Not "or". (2) The negation of $L\lesssim H$ is in fact $L \gg H$, not $L \gtrsim H$.

Comment: A third point, since $H \approx H'$, the relation is $$P_L I^+(u_{H'}, v_H) \neq 0 \iff L \lesssim H $$
Two high frequencies can interact to produce something of much lower frequencies, but not something with very high frequency.

Comment: You seem to be rusty with your "Littlewood-Paley Trichotomy" computations. I suggest re-reading http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.01w/notes3.ps or  the Appendix of Tao's _Nonlinear Dispersive Equations_ (Principle A.5 is what is at work here).

Comment: I understand your first 2 points and your right about me not knowing enough about these general principles. I looked in your two references but they mostly concern Differentiation. I'm interested in a proof of your statement "Two high frequencies can interact to produce something of much lower frequencies, but not something with very high frequency." I could not find that in your references, as Principle A.5 is "just" an heuristic.

Comment: Let me try this in n=1 for simplicities sake: Let $H'\sim H$. I want to know where $u_Lv_H\neq 0$ so I calculate using fourirtransformation and convolution: $$(u_{H'}v_H)^\wedge(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi_{H'}(y-x) \psi_H(x) u(y-x) v(x) dx $$ Therefore $$supp((u_{H'}v_H)^\wedge)=(y: \exists x \ with \  H/2\leq x\leq2H  \ and \ H'/2\leq y-x \leq 2H')=(y: (H+H')/2 \leq y \leq 2(H+H'))=(y: y \sim H)$$. This exact calculation worked for the case $L<<H$ but here it seems to to fail. And I'm unsure how that works with n>1 since I have to deal with $|y-x| $ instead of $y-x$ then.

Comment: You are doing it wrong _on multiple levels_. The support of $\psi_H$ is something like $ 2^{H-1} \leq |x| \leq 2^{H+1}$. Note first the absolute value sign. And note secondly the dyadic nature of the bounds (2 to the some power and not just a number)! // I am afraid at this point I can only throw my hands up and say that I don't have the time to help you read a paper line-by-line. Go back and really read the references that I pointed you to (Terry's lecture notes very clearly explain this on the bottom of page 2 and top of page 3). If you really want to learn this you have to actually ...

Comment: ... spend some time sitting down with the definitions and compute a little bit.